# Ajax alerts the response, but won't add it to the dom

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this function handling ajax calls:

```
function ajaxPost (divNode, parameters, file) {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
    divNode.appendChild (xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("POST", file, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(parameters);
}
```

The alert about halfway down gives me the expected output from the given php file, but for some reason, I don't seem able to append it to the dom. I have checked the divNode is actually a div element & I'm successfully using appendChild else-where, so I'm at a loss to understand the problem here.

What is different about an Ajax call to disrupt normal javascript functions and how do I work around it?

Comment: Does the ResponseText contain HTML code? From javascrip's point of view, the response is just a string... You're appending a string as a DOM element... You may want to cast that string to HTML elements somehow.

Comment: `appendChild` needs a DOM element as a parameter, not a string. This would be much, much easier using a library like jQuery

Comment: `xmlhttp` is a global, you are probably risking race conditions here.

Comment: I thought that passing the reponse back with html tags in it, made it count as a DOM element. Good to clear that up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `appendChild` method takes an `HTMLElementNode` (or other DOM node object) as an argument, not a `String`

You need to build a DOM tree using `createElement` and `createTextNode` and then append that. This is a good solution combined with a server returning a neat data structure expressed in JSON.

Alternatively, you could look at `innerHTML`.

Comment: Ok, I have this working with innerHTML - which isn't exactly what I wanted but it'll do for now. Think when I have time I will add another parameter to the function to pass responseText to a processing function and kieep this one generic.

Comment: Any messages sent between a PHP program on a web server and a JavaScript program on a web browser are sent over HTTP. This essentially means text. If you want to use structured data, then you have to serialise it to text and then deserialise it back to a data structure — hence the suggestion to use JSON.

Comment: The best way to communicate information is to convert your PHP array into JSON before sending it, thus making it much easier to use on the JS side. see http://json.org for further information

Comment: I'll look into JSON for the future - too tight a deadline for now.

Answer (score -1):

Change `divNode.appendChild (xmlhttp.responseText);`

to

**jQuery:**

`$(divNode).appendChild (xmlhttp.responseText);`

And change what you're passing in as divNode to something like `'.classname' or '#idname'`

Or **Non jQuery:**

`document.getElementById(divNode).appen`... divNode would need to be an ID of the element

Comment: This assumes that the problem is that `divNode` is a string (which is unlikely given the name) and that `responseText` is not a string (which, even if you didn't know the basics of the XHR object, would be unlikely given the name).

Comment: I wasn't assuming that it's a string.  It assumes that the divNode isn't having the xmlhttp.responseText added (which he stated is successfully received) to the divNode element.  So, my attempt to help/troubleshoot is to confirm the element is the right one.